# iOS: Position UIImage in UIImageView to top while maintaining aspect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'd like to be able to scale an image to fit within uiimage view as well as align it to the top. It's a little difficult to describe but here is an image to explain what I'm attempting to achieve:

[image: 1]

Figure 2 is what I can get, but Figure 3 is what I want to be able to do.

Comment: There was a solution I saw that was close but it was from 2011 or 2010. Hoping something has come up in the past 4 years.

Comment: have you tried  cellImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: @Garry I have. And it doesn't scale. I'd like to use ScaleFill so it scales down to the width of the UIImageView, but then position it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with standard UIImageView behaviour. 
For fully customizable alignment you have to subclass UIImageView and implement alignment by your self or use third party library.

For example [UIImageViewAligned](https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned) will fits your needs. I'm using it and it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already using SDImageCache for this as well. If I there is a simple way to explain it I'll add it to their UIImageView subclass